# Stripe API redirectToCheckout not redirecting to the correct url in Next.js

Tags: next.js, cors, stripe-payments

In Next.js the Stripe redirectToCheckout function is sending the checkout page to a url that fails, but the json response data is full and the url is correct (works if I try it manually). Stripe is not sending the checkout to the session.url for some reason.

How can we have the redirectToCheckout redirect to the session.url?

I'm currently using this...

```
await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: id });
```

I've tried what the Stripe docs suggest...

```
res.redirect(303, session.url);
```

But that gives a CORS error - CORS request external redirect not allowed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cool, but what CORS error?

Comment: redirecting did give a CORs error, now it's giving You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId if I use res.redirect(303, session.url);

Comment: The actual CORS error was Reason: CORS request external redirect not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by explicitly telling Next.js the names of the stripe API keys in the next.config.js file.

next.config.js

```
   env: {
     stripe_public_key_test: process.env.stripe_public_key_test,
     stripe_secret_key_test: process.env.stripe_secret_key_test,
     stripe_webhook_endpoint_secret: process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET,
      },
```

Restart the app after editing the next.config.js file

I ended up using `await stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: id });`

Comment: Thanks so much for posting.  I had all the other settings in the right place on the server side of processing stripe, but the nextjs public facing side of the site definitely needs the Publishable key, too.